# Skiasharp Save desktop image to file (Windows)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using net core for a web project.
I have installed in System.Drawing.Common (Nuget) to save the deskop screen to a file.
In .NET (Web too) I do it without problems, but netcore is not giving me processes with Bitmap. (It informs me that : System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform.)

I have installed skiasharp (Nuget)

Can someone please give me a complete example of simply saving the desktop screen using skiasharp?
Thank you

Comment: I have not found the solution.
I will ask how can I use desktop as canvas using skipsharp.
This is how I would fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Drawing namespace is not recommended for new development because it is not supported in Windows Services, ASP.NET Core, and ASP.NET.

You can use **[ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)**, **[SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)** instead.

You want to use skiasharp, you can download the source code of this project, maybe it will help you:

https://github.com/hongbai/FontsPrint